# Cancelling out duplicates in a list by even parity

Tags: python, list, duplicates, logic

Let's say we have a list such that `list = ["1", "2", "1", "3", "3", "4", "3"]`

I need a way to remove any duplicates and cancel them out in case there is a total even number of those duplicates. Otherwise, if there is an odd number, only one element would remain.
For example, our list would filter to `["2", "3", "4"]`

In my case, this list would initially be empty elements added during runtime. I need little time complexity as this list is used in real time for drawing shapes (trying my luck in pygame).

I came across this potential solution to my problem:

```
def my_function(x):
  return list(dict.fromkeys(x))

mylist = my_function(["a", "b", "a", "c", "c"])
print(mylist) #from https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_howto_remove_duplicates.asp
```

I can't get my head around how to implement this cancelling out without overcomplicating it. Thank you for reading.

Comment: "I need little time complexity as this list is used in real time for drawing shapes" I can't understand why the algorithm is useful. What exactly do the list values represent?

Comment: "1" and "3" has same number of occurences, so they should produce same result though

Comment: @Karl Knechtel they represent indices for buttons. The idea is that if we click a button once, it would change colour - but if we click it twice then it would return to its original colour and so on.

Comment: @sahasrara62 I am so sorry - have not slept for 40 hours when writing the example, there should be two elements "1" whereas three elements "3". This is why "1" must not be present whereas "3" must. - EDITED NOW

Comment: Okay, so you don't care about the order of the retained results, then?  That's pretty significant for solutions.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel Exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Counter..!**

Counter - A subclass of `dict` that's specially designed for counting hashable objects in Python / occurences of the objects.

**Code:  Time-O(n) Space-O(n)**

```
from collections import Counter
lis = ["1", "2", "1", "3", "1" , "3", "4", "3"]

a=Counter(lis)
res=[]
for key,value in a.items():
    if value%2!=0:
        res.append(key)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

**I think you made a typo in first example output.. 1 should also added cause 1 occurence is odd..**

**Below code by dictionary..!  Time- O(n) Space-O(n)**

**Code:**

```
lis = ["1", "2", "1", "3", "1" , "3", "4", "3"]
dic,res={},[]

for num in lis:
    dic[num]=dic.get(num,0)+1
    
for key,value in dic.items():
    if value%2!=0:
        res.append(key)
print(res)  #Same output.
```

**Updated part.**

**list comprehension**.

```
lis = ["1", "2", "1", "3", "1" , "3", "4", "3"]
dic={}

for num in lis:
    dic[num]=dic.get(num,0)+1
    
res=[key for key,value in dic.items() if value%2!=0]

print(res)  #Same output.
```

Comment: The loop can just as easily be a list comprehension: `[key for key, value in a.items() if value % 2]`.

Comment: yes you are right list comprehension be quite handy..! @KarlKnechtel Updated!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that should work for your case:

```
def remove_duplicates(lst):
    result = []
    counts = {}
    for elem in lst:
        if elem in counts:
            counts[elem] += 1
        else:
            counts[elem] = 1
    for elem, count in counts.items():
        if count % 2 == 1:
            result.append(elem)
    return result

lst = ["1", "2", "1", "3", "1", "3", "4","4","3"]
#here 4 is in list two times(even)
result = remove_duplicates(lst)
print(result)
```

This solution first counts the number of occurrences of each element in the list using a dictionary. Then, it iterates through the dictionary and appends elements with an odd number of occurrences to the result list. This should give you the desired behavior of cancelling out even occurrences of duplicates and keeping only one element if there are an odd number of duplicates.

This solution should have a time complexity of O(n) because it iterates through the list once to count the occurrences and then again to process the counts. This should make it suitable for use in real-time applications.

Comment: you can apply `dic.get()` so that no need of if else condition..!

Answer (score 1):

Use `collections.Counter()` and a list comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter

list_ = Counter(["1", "2", "1", "3", "1", "3", "4", "3"])  # with three "1"
res = [k for k, v in list_.items() if v % 2 == 1]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Comment: I am sorry - For the input, there should be two elements "1" whereas three elements "3". This is why "1" must not be present whereas "3" must. - EDITED NOW

Comment: Please use comments to explain issues with how the question is written; don't include it in your answer. Keep in mind that this is not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `set` that keeps track of all of the items that have occurred an odd number of times. Iterate over the items in your input list : if the item is in the set already, then remove it. Otherwise add it.

```
items = ["1", "2", "1", "3", "1", "3", "4", "3"]

theSet=set()
for i in items:
    if i in theSet:
        theSet.remove(i)
    else:
        theSet.add(i)

print(theSet)
```

Comment: If there are issues with how the question is written, please use the comment section to explain how the question can be edited or otherwise improved. Typos that are incidental to the question should be fixed; typos that are the actual cause of the question are a reason to close the question, unless the question is **explicitly about** the typo (i.e. how it should be typed instead, or why it is invalid code). Please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**. I edited this answer to remove that commentary.